# Installing Enchant Library + PyEnchant

Tags: python, nmake, pyenchant, enchant

I'm currently trying to install the Enchant library in order to use it with PyEnchant for a project I'm working on. I've checked out the source from the official SVN repo and found a document instructing me how to correctly build the source into a release:

http://svn.abisource.com/enchant/trunk/msvc/Build.win32.readme

However, I found the resultant binary files elsewhere and decided to grab them and see what was inside etc. I found this:

http://i.gyazo.com/33e3d2e79cf03182725466dfbefc1dc6.png

And inside the lib directory: http://gyazo.com/e9a0097ce96e5f1bc0859ec80076f38c

The instructions referenced above make mention of 6 different files that need to be copied from one place to another, however I have no idea where this mystery location is nor why it makes this library magically work. The instructions in question are:

```
copy iconv.dll and intl.dll from c:\usr\bin to enchant\lib\glib\release
copy libglib-2.0-0-vs8.dll and libgmodule-2.0-0.dll to enchant\lib\glib\release
copy glib-2.0-vs8.lib and gmodule-2.0-vs8.lib to enchant\lib\glib\lib\release
```

Any assistance with this would be GREATLY appreciated as it's driving me up the wall, I hate not knowing something especially considering it's probably something blatantly obvious and that I should know.

Also, you should know that I'm using Python 3.4 on an amd64 machine/installation so the prebuilt packages for PyEnchant that contain Enchant are not an option, or at least as far as I know.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Lewis Watts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling I discovered how to solve this problem, simply take the binary files produced by the build and place them in a location known to the compiler such as in the directory PyEnchant makes or add another path to the project structure.

I have still been unable to get Enchant to work due to the whole 64 bit shenanigans but that's an altogether different can of worms.

Comment: So it is not possible to use PyEnchant with Python 3.4?

Comment: Not with Python 3.4 64 bit from what I've seen. Have a crack at it with 32 bit and you should meet success. In theory/

Comment: I put the library into the proper directory but I get several assertion errors trying to get suggestions from pyenchant :-(

Comment: If you've gotten that far you've gotten further than I did :) From what I've seen PyEnchant is somewhat troublesome on Python 3.4, not sure if it's even worth the effort. I've been using whoosh and a dictionary file for my purposes, not fantastic but it gets the job done.